# How to make joins between arrays filled by integers in PhP?

Tags: php, arrays

What I try is to get the join between 2 arrays filled with some integers. The result I would have is :

> 1st array -> [1] [2] [3] [4]
>   2nd array -> [2] [4] [6] [8]

Join between these array would be `-> [2] [4]` because these numbers appear in the both arrays.

Is there any kind of function which do exactly this result in php ? I found around implode but that seems to be not what I am searching for. Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**array_intersect()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) :

```
array_intersect($array1,$array2);
```

#### [Demo](https://eval.in/165515)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your short code of this function :-) !